# Is it ok to say "fill in the blank spaces"?

Tags: expressions

There is a dispute between two guys in our village. One guy says "fill in the blank spaces" is not right and instead "fill in the blanks" should be used. Now I know "fill in the blanks" is right but is there something wrong with saying "fill in the blank spaces"?

Comment: You may find these examples useful: > 1. *When you have filled in the blanks, hand the form back to me*. (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English) > 2. *Please fill in the blanks.* (Oxford Advanced Learner's) >3. *Fill in the blanks in this form*. (Cambridge Advanced Learner's)

Comment: They're both correct, the first is more descriptive the second shorter and probably for this reason alone, is more often found in forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends on what is meant by "blank."

> [**blank**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Blank?s=t): 1. a space in a printed form, test, etc., to be filled in: *Write your name in the blank*.
>   2. (chiefly US) a printed form containing such spaces: *Have you filled out one of these blanks?*

And so, if your friend had in mind the latter definition, saying "fill in the [**blank spaces**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blank+space)" makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes and no. Typically, you fill *out* a blank [form], but fill *in* a blank [space].

Comment: There is a specific portion in almost all tests, examinations in which one has to fill the blanks. e.g. This is a _____ pen. 1. Blue 2. Red 3. Green. Now which one suits? Is any of it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Fill in the blank spaces is not an incorrect answer, rather can be categorized under **Pleonasm**.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're talking about filling in a form that has blank spaces for people's responses, or some kind of quiz where you have to supply a missing word.

"Fill in the blank spaces" is not *grammatically* incorrect, but it's not *idiomatic English* either. The second guy is right.

Comment: How can you say that, when you yourself use that phrase? -- *"I assume you're talking about filling in a form that has* ***blank spaces*** *for people's responses, . . ."*

Comment: @F.E. - In that context, 'blank spaces' is purely descriptive, and is actually desirable in the interest of clarity. "To fill in the blanks" is the idiomatic way of describing what you do when you supply the missing data.

Comment: It may not be idiomatic American English. They are both common in British English and given they are both grammatically valid, as @Elian indicated, the latter could be clearer to e.g. a non-native speaker.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same US - UK divide, but on checking on Google Ngrams, the ratio of frequencies they pick up of "filling in the blank spaces" : "filling in the spaces: is actually higher (about 1 : 2) in their 'US English' corpus. The notion of 'filled / occupied spaces', short for 'ex-spaces' I assume, probably drives the usage.